# Using AP Mode or WDS Bridge to broadcast IPTV

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wds, iptv

Let's same our perceptions first.
My ISP came with a GPON Wireless Router to give us Internet and IPTV.

Internet is set on Port 1, Port 2, and Port 3 while IPTV is set on Port 4

Let's focus on IPTV since it is the focus of this question.
Can I just broadcast Port 4 with Wireless AP then Recieve the AP with a router then connect it to my STB?

This is the topology that I propose:
Port 4 >>> Wireless AP Mode in 5GHz on TP-Link Router (Transmit) >>> WDS Mode in 5 GHz on TP-Link Router (Recieve) >>> LAN Cable to STB >>> TV

In theory... I think it is feasible but I am not sure.
If It is feasible I will save a lot of time and money from wiring.

Please keep in mind that I will use home use router such as Archer A6v2 as Wireless AP and another Archer A6v2 as reciever in WDS Mode.

Comment: Probably not, but you should ask your ISP.

Comment: Why it can't?
My ISP has bad technical support, they probably try to sell me Powerwall for the monthly subscription...